# How can I create multilevel heading in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a data frame heading like this:[image]

As a beginner I could only try this:

```
Final=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Before','After'],['Total', 'Time','Year'],['Day','Month']])
```

How can I create the headers? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Since you have three levels, you need to add 3 lists, the index of each codes list represent an element from levels.

```
Final = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['Before','After'],['Total', 'Time','Year'],['AM','PM','Day','Month','']],
               codes=[[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
                      [0,1,1,2,2,0,1,1,2,2],
                      [4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3]])

pd.DataFrame(columns = Final)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think here is a bit complicated `Multiindex`, so is possible create tuples passed to [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html). Always is necessary specify all 3 levels, so for `Total` are used empty strings:

```
tuples = [('Before','Total',''),
          ('Before','Time1','AM'),
          ('Before','Time1','PM'),
          ('Before','Year1','Day'),
          ('Before','Year1','Month'),
          ('After','Total',''),
          ('After','Time1','AM'),
          ('After','Time1','PM'),
          ('After','Year1','Day'),
          ('After','Year1','Month')]
           
Final=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2], columns=Final)
print (df)
  Before                        After                       
   Total Time1      Year1       Total Time1      Year1      
            AM   PM   Day Month          AM   PM   Day Month
1    NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2    NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```